# How do I call notifyDataSetChanged() from a AsyncTask that is in another class

Tags: java, android

So I am trying to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the ArrayList on completion of `OnPostExecute` However I am finding it quite hard to do with the AsyncTask being in another class. I also cannot call it in `setpagecontent` as it is a static method.

I appreciate all the help provided :)

Comment: either use eventBus or listerner.

Comment: You can make a static variable for  ArrayAdapter<RedditPost> PostsAdaptor. and call   PostsAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged(); inside setPageContent(). So the code like:          public static void setPageContent(String thePageContent) {
        System.out.println("Got: " + thePageContent);
        String jsonFromReddit = thePageContent;
        ArrayList<RedditPost> posts = RedditPostHelper.getRedditPostsFromJSON(jsonFromReddit);
        Posts_Array_List.addAll(posts);
     PostsAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }

Comment: @Priyanka Thanks for your answer could you please add it as an answer so I would be able to view the code in proper syntax :)

Comment: @Priyanka How would I go about making the static variable?

Comment: please check the below code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostListActivity.java

```
 public class PostListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   ArrayList<String> Posts_Array_List = new ArrayList<String>();
    //  private RequestQueue mQueue;
 ArrayAdapter<String> PostsAdaptor;
 ListView lv;
 Context mContext;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_list);
    mContext=PostListActivity.this;
     lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LV_Post_list);

    PostsAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PostListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Posts_Array_List);
    PostsAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(PostsAdaptor);
    String stringUrl = "https://www.reddit.com/r/cars/hot.json?limit=1";

    new DownloadAsyncTask(mContext,stringUrl).execute();
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        String myParam = extras.getString("paramPosition");
        // Get the URL from the UI's text field.
    }
}

public void setPageContent(String thePageContent) {
    System.out.println("Got: " + thePageContent);
    String jsonFromReddit = thePageContent;
    //ArrayList<String> posts = RedditPostHelper.getRedditPostsFromJSON(jsonFromReddit);
   // Posts_Array_List.addAll(posts);
    Posts_Array_List.add(thePageContent);
    System.out.println("result==="+thePageContent);
    PostsAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

DownloadAsyncTask.java

```
 public class DownloadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
private Context context;
private String url;
DownloadAsyncTask(Context mContext, String stringUrl)
{
    super();
    this.context=mContext;
    this.url=stringUrl;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    String result="testing";
    return result;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (!result.isEmpty() && result !=null){
        PostListActivity pla = (PostListActivity) context;
        pla.setPageContent(result);
    }

}
```

Output:

[image]}

Comment: Error: 
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference

Comment: Same Error IDK what to do

Comment: otherwise call list again in setPageContent().. i updated the code

Comment: ```PostListActivity.this``` Cannot be called from a static method

Comment: otherwise,,we can use the static context,, and pass it ArraryAdapter..

Comment: I think Better to Use the EventBus /otherwise use Listener. for updating the view

Comment: Could you please provide the code to use an EventBus or Listener?

Comment: @Bats i edited the code.. just tried once.. bcoz.. in my project,, it works perfectly.... ..

Comment: Well obviously that is going to work, because there is now no background task

Comment: i tried in my system... do ur task in background, wat ever u want.. main part is,, u have to call the activity in your PostExcute().

Comment: if (!result.isEmpty() && result !=null){
        PostListActivity pla = (PostListActivity) context;
        pla.setPageContent(result);
    }

Comment: the context,, which u pass at the time of  calling Async task,, the same context u will use in postexecute().. method ,then it will update your view.

Answer (score 0):

There would be some changes to be made to the code but for inter class communication you can use an interface and use its functions as callbacks

Comment: Sorry pretty new to android and java, in general, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Ok lets try this ...Use the post execute method of the Async Task .... here you should be able to notify the adapter about changes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441298/android-call-notifydatasetchanged-from-asynctask - check this out

Comment: That is not relevant as the classes are different and is static

Comment: My ArrayAdapter is in another class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36218815/android-thread-communication-asynctask -  this is how it can be done via interfaces